# Provide notification of successful action after dismissing view in swift

Tags: swift, api, notifications

So far, I've been able to load data using my API, like this:

```
let api = APIController(delegate: self) 
api.request("get_student_list")

func didRecieveAPIResults(originalRequest: String,apiResponse: APIResponse) {
    // do stuff with API response here
}
```

That's been working great for the situation where the user opens a view, the data loads, and then the view is refreshed. (For example, loading a list of students)

I would now like to create something like this:

Click on student in student list view > Grades list opens > Click on grade in grades list view > Grades list dismissed >  Success/failure notification given

Would it be best to set the delegate to the students view, so that when I dismiss the grades view, the students view receives the `didRecieveAPIResults` signal, or is there a better way of dealing with this?

In case this is relevant, it might make sense to have a common way for success notifications to appear throughout the app - e.g. a blue box at the bottom of the screen that briefly shows and then hides itself. I'm not quite sure how to do that yet though.

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want a notification that can get sent to any object,  then you would want to look into `NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter()`  particularly `addObserver` for the listener object and `postNotificationName` when sending the notice.  if it is just a simple success failure request,  I would just have the api.request call return a Bool value, then the coder using your api would do something as follows:

```
let success = api.request....
if(!success)
{
  //Houston we have a problem
}
```

You could also elaborate it more by having it be an Int value,  with it returning an error code instead of just a bool value

how to use notification

...end of api request

```
let userInfo = ["originalRequest":originalRequest,"response": apiResponse];
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("API_SUCCESS",object:nil,userInfo:userInfo);
```

then inside of whatever class would need to know the notification

```
init....
{
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "APISuccess:", name: "API_SUCCESS", object: nil);
}
func APISuccess(notification:NSNotification)
{
    if let userInfo = notification.userInfo
    {
        didRecieveAPIResults(originalRequest: userInfo["originalRequest"] as! String ,apiResponse: userInfo["response"] as! APIResponse)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that looks very promising. Am I right to say you'd send the request from the grades view, wait for the response, and then pop the view? (Presumably covering up all the controls with another UIView so that the user doesn't click twice) Or is there a way to set the AppDelegate (or something) as the delegate for the API response, so that you can pop the view straight away?

Comment: how it works, is you send a notification,  and any object that is listening for this particular notification will receive it.  Upon receiving,  you do whatever you want with it.  so in your case,  at the end of your API call, you post a notification,  then the view I guess? will receive the notification.  and you can call didRecieveAPIResults.  Let me update my answer to show you

Comment: Perfect, thank you! For anybody else following this question, I'm now using the App Delegate as the delegate for my API request, meaning I can pop the view immediately as the App Delegate is listening for the response, which can then use `NSNotificationCenter` to post a notification. My students view can then listen for that notification and provide visual feedback as wanted.

Comment: Just want to point out to people that this method was if you wanted the notification to be received outside of the appdelegate( or whatever call has the api delegate object).  If inside the appdelegate( or whatever call has the api delegate object),  you would just use the regular way to receive delegate calls